# Calling powershell script using java swing

Tags: java, powershell

I am trying to call a powershell script using java.. My code is not working... 
I have created a login window. While clicking the login button the powershell script need to be invoked...

```
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Credential extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Credential()
    {
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel()
        {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (g instanceof Graphics2D) 
                {
                final int R = 250;
                final int G = 220;
                final int B = 250;
                Paint p = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(R, G, B, 0),
                                        0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(R, G, B, 255), true);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setPaint(p);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 45);
                g2d.setFont(font);
                g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                g2d.drawString("Get Credential",60,80);
        }
    }

};
//Container contentPane = Jframe.getContentPane();
//contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setContentPane(panel);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
placeComponents(panel);

    }
    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(40, 100, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(130,100, 160, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(40, 140, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(130, 140, 160, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setBounds(100, 180, 80, 25);
        runn();
        panel.add(loginButton);

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("cancel");
        cancelButton.setBounds(220, 180, 80, 25);
         cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                  // statusLabel.setText("abcd");
                      System.exit(0);
                } });
        panel.add(cancelButton);
    }

public void runn() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell C:\\testscript.ps1");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge
            = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported
            = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
    if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) 
    {
        System.out.println("Per-pixel translucency is not supported");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         Credential gtw = new Credential();
         gtw.setVisible(true);
             }
    });
}
```

}

I would also like to know whether I can use jni to call powershell using java class.. I am getting error as:

```
Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runn() from the type Credential
at Credential.placeComponents(Credential.java:82)
at Credential.<init>(Credential.java:57)
at Credential$2.run(Credential.java:136)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Comment: Check the error stream as well. My guess would be the execution policy.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> My code is not working?

Are you getting any error?. If so , what is that.? Can you post your Exception Trace.

From your code `Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell D:\\exportasxml.ps1");`

Did you set  powershell path to the environment variable? You need to make sure that the command you are executing  is in the correct path.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:at Credential.main(Credential.java:97)` This is the error...